# I am preparing The Lion King themed summer camp for young children, am I allowed to use The Lion King poster on my pamphlets?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

This summer I am preparing a summer camp for children which is strongly inspired by The Lion King story line and I like the posters created for the movie.

Is it OK to use the posters as images on my own pamphlets for parents, so they can read more information about the camp?

By the way, I am from the Europe, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Can you contact Disney and ask for permission or to license whatever Lion King IP you need for this purpose? If you're buying all the Lion King props/materials retail you're probably free to use them at your camp. The only license you'd need is to advertise your camp as being Lion King themed. Disney's a big company and surely you're not the first person who has wanted to license IP for a small business. Go through the proper channels and fear nothing. Disney might even help you - for a cut, presumably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do whatever you want: you live in a free country. You will probably be successfully sued by Disney for trade mark infringement and copyright breach, Again because you live in a free country you can pay the damages or force Disney to send you bankrupt and take all your stuff. Disney operates out of a free country too: they might not do this, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: I guess I should have edited my question into: Can I do *that* and know that Disney would have nothing against me to sue me? I understand I cannot. Thank you for the answer, Dale.